# How should I create a table based in the following requirements? [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have got the following JSON file:

```
"vehicle_number" : 91,
"pit_stops" : [ {
  "pit_in_elapsed_time" : 1874.0926,
  "pit_out_elapsed_time" : 0.0
}, {
  "pit_in_elapsed_time" : 1992.9723,
  "pit_out_elapsed_time" : 0.0
}, {
  "pit_in_elapsed_time" : 2862.2129,
  "pit_out_elapsed_time" : 0.0
} ],
```

My table has to keep the following value:

- vehicle
- pit_int_elapsed_time
- pit_out_elapse_time

How do I create a table based on this??

```
create table pitstop (
 vehicle varchar(50) not null,
 inTime varchar(50) not null,
 outTime varchar(50) not null,
 constraint pk_id primary key(inTime, outTime))
```

I am not sure if this would be the ideal way of create the table?

Regards

**EDIT**

I have been thinking of creating 2 main tables.  One for the vehicles (vehicleID as pk, pitstopFK  as foreign key).

```
create table vehicles (     
 vehicle varchar(50) primary key not null 
 pitstops_fk int not null );
```

Also the pitstops table:

```
create table pitstops (
 id int primary key autoincrement not null,
 inTime varchar(50) not null,
 outTime varchar(50) not null,
 constraint u_time UNIQUE (inTime, outTime))
```

**vehicles ----- pitstops  ( 1 to many)**

Comment: It could be that another vehicle had exactly the same (inTime, outTime)... so I guess that primary key wouldn´t be legit ???    what do you think guys?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say much without a better understanding of the problem you're trying to solve, but I would say:

- if vehicle ID is always an integer, an unsigned int will generally perform better than treating it as text
- using a SQL date type for the inTime and outTime columns will allow you to use SQL time/date operations. If the timestamps represent real-world times consider DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, if they are elapsed seconds since the start of a race or something like that, a floating point numeric type would probably be a better choice.
- the combination of inTime and outTime doesn't make sense as a primary key, since as you note in the comment it is not necessarily unique. In thinking about designating a primary key, don't (just) think about uniqueness, but about how you'd want to refer to a pitstop event from other tables. In the case I would probably suggest a synthetic auto-incremented unsigned int as a primary key.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
Well,  if I put an autoincremental id as pk I will be allowing the table to get repeated values??   ID, vehicleID, inTime, outTime.

Comment: To be honest the primary key shoud  be formed by the three elements:  vehicle, inTime, outTime.  But I think this is not right..

Comment: There's always a decision to be made as to what extent one wants to use schema to enforce rules on the data. Yes, with a synthetic PK you could have multiple rows with the same vehicleID, inTime, and outTime - which would indicate an error. But presumably it would also be an error to have the same vehicle with overlapping inTime and outTime ranges - which you can't detect with schema.

Comment: Consider that any time you want to efficiently refer to a pitstop from another table, with a compound PK you will have to store all of those fields, which can be unwieldy.

A uniqueness constraint could still be used separately to enforce unique (vehicle, in, out) conditions should you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if it is a time you want to store in your database i wouldn't use varchar. Instead try to use Float or Real.

The next thing is, that you should take your vehicle in your primary key as well.

I also would recommend to introduce a ID to your Database.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE pitstop (
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
vehicle varchar(50) NOT NULL,
inTime float NOT NULL,
outTime float NOT NULL,
constraint pk_id primary key(ID, vehicle))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think I have not explained myself well.  Within the table I can have repeated vehicles but with different (inTime, outTime)...  ok, I might have to create two tables.     One for Vehicles and another one for pitstops (inTime, outTime) ?????

Comment: Then you should like you said, Create 2 Tables one for the vehicles and one for in and out-times with a foreign key to a specific vehicle